# Why does developing a firefox extension involve installing an sdk?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm currently trying to port a Chrome extension into a Firefox add-on, but the development process is incredibly different, and the part in particular that I find confusing is why I should have to install an SDK.

How are these two so different?  Do Firefox add-ons run faster because they're precompiled?  Why aren't firefox add-ons just HTML and javascript like (some) Chrome ones?

What's going on behind the scenes here that involves using [so much command line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm#Installation) just to get a firefox addon started?

Comment: You don't need SDK as long as you can package XPI manually. It is a ZIP file with Javascript and XML metadata

Comment: The jpm installs some helper tools, for beginners trust me its very easy. It does everything for you. It follow the node.js npm style of doing things. Check it out - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_Started_%28jpm%29 - the jpm sdk is not as big as other sdk's at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK exists to help developers build their extentions, but if you don't want to use it there is also a way.

You can use [web extensions](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/08/21/the-future-of-developing-firefox-add-ons/) which as the [wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebExtensions) says have their benefits:

- Porting add-ons to and from other browsers should be easier.
- Reviewing add-ons for addons.mozilla.org should be easier.
- WebExtensions must be compatible with multiprocess Firefox (Electrolysis).
- Changes to Firefox's internal code should be less likely to break add-ons.
- WebExtensions should be easier to use than the existing Firefox XPCOM/XUL APIs.

I don't have personal experience with web extension but it seems to be promising for someone who does not want to use SDK and the benefits ofthe web extensions are that they support an enrich `manifest` document and you only need to zip your extension and run it.

There are some [examples](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples) on github to get started.